# Pandas rank by column value

Tags: pandas, dataframe, rank

I have a dataframe that has auction IDs and bid prices. The dataframe is sorted by auction id (ascending) and bid price (descending):

```
Auction_ID    Bid_Price
123           9
123           7
123           6
123           2
124           3
124           2
124           1
125           1
```

I'd like to add a column called 'Auction_Rank' that ranks auction id's by bid prices:

```
Auction_ID    Bid_Price    Auction_Rank
123           9            1
123           7            2
123           6            3
123           2            4
124           3            1
124           2            2
124           1            3
125           1            1
```

Comment: Why do bid prices 9 and 1 both have a rank of 1? And why auction_id 124 and 125, both bid price 1, have different ranks?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Here's one way to do it in Pandas-way

You could [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.groupby.html) on `Auction_ID` and take [`rank()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.rank.html) on `Bid_Price` with `ascending=False`

```
In [68]: df['Auction_Rank'] = df.groupby('Auction_ID')['Bid_Price'].rank(ascending=False)

In [69]: df
Out[69]:
   Auction_ID  Bid_Price  Auction_Rank
0         123          9             1
1         123          7             2
2         123          6             3
3         123          2             4
4         124          3             1
5         124          2             2
6         124          1             3
7         125          1             1
```

Comment: What if you wanted to groupby only `Auction_ID==124`? Similar to dpylr's filter function in R

Comment: `df['Auction_Rank'] = df.loc[df['Auction_ID'] == 124, :].groupby('Auction_ID')['Bid_Price'].rank(ascending=False)`

Comment: What if need to rank except one particular column?

Comment: @Zero This answer doesn't work for me. the code: df = pd.DataFrame({'Auction_ID':[1,2,3,4], 'Bid_Price':[7, 10, 5, 3]}); df['Auction_Rank'] = df.groupby('Auction_ID')['Bid_Price'].rank(ascending=False); df yields [1,1,1,1] at Auction_Rank column.

Comment: what if all the columns are in string