# Pandas rank by column value with conditions

Tags: python, sorting, pandas

I have the following dataset **(non-unique id)** :

```
id   data  country
1    8     B
2    15    A
3    14    D
3    19    D
3    8     C
3    20    A
```

For rows with **country ANYTHING BUT "A"**, I want to add a "rank" column.

For rows with **country "A"**, I want to leave "rank" value empty (or 0).

Expected output :

```
id   data  country rank
1    8     B       1
2    15    A       0
3    14    D       3 
3    19    D       4
3    8     C       2
3    20    A       0
```

This post [Pandas rank by column value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30425796/pandas-rank-by-column-value) gives great insight.

I can try :

```
df['rank'] = df['data'].rank(ascending=True)
```

but I don't know how to take "country" into account ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT: Written before an edit to the question so doesn't do exactly what the OP wants.**

```
df['rank_A'] = df.data[df['country']=='A'].rank(ascending=True)
```

Tested on this

```
 import pandas as pd
 from pandas import DataFrame
 import numpy as np
 df2 = DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 2))
 df2.columns = ['A','B']
 df2['rank'] = df2.A[df2['B']>0].rank(ascending=True)
 df2
```

which gives the ranking according to A for rows in which B is greater than zero.

Comment: note you'll get NaN in the rank column for rows which belong to B

Comment: I think you could do it this way: `df['rank'] = 0; df.ix[df.country != 'A', 'rank'] = df.ix[df['country'] != 'A', 'data'].rank(ascending=True, method='first').astype(int)`

Comment: @MaxU, Can you use rank with two columns?