# Pandas how to group, sort and rank columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset as shown:

```
student_id     course_marks
1234           10
9887           30
9881           20
5634           40
5634           50
1234           60
1234           70
```

I want to sort them using course_marks, then rank them within their student_id

expected:

```
student_id     course_marks   rank
1234           10             1
1234           60             2
1234           70             3
5634           40             1
5634           50             2
9887           20             1
9887           30             2
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas rank by column value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30425796/pandas-rank-by-column-value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df['rank'] = df.groupby('student_id')['course_marks'].rank()
```

```
   student_id  course_marks  rank
0        1234            10   1.0
1        9887            30   1.0
2        9881            20   1.0
3        5634            40   1.0
4        5634            50   2.0
5        1234            60   2.0
6        1234            70   3.0
```

or, sorted:

```
   student_id  course_marks  rank
0        1234            10   1.0
5        1234            60   2.0
6        1234            70   3.0
3        5634            40   1.0
4        5634            50   2.0
2        9881            20   1.0
1        9887            30   1.0
```

(Note that you have `9881` and `9887` in your example data, and `9887` twice in your expected output.)

Comment: it is ranking as 1,2,2,4,4,6 instead of 1,2,2,3,3,4?